# How to handle ESOCKETTIMEDOUT while getblobtostream() azure storage?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

While trying to get all the blobs using getBlobToStream() following error is displayed.How can I handle it?

I also came across "ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter" but not sure how to use it.
So far did not find any code related to it.

```
            blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(containerName, path, null, (err, data) => {
             
                    data.entries.forEach(entry => {
                        var options = {
                            rangeStart: 0,
                            rangeEnd: entry.contentLength
                        };
                        if (fs.existsSync(fileUploadPath)) {
                            var sourceFilePath = fileUploadPath + '/' + project.id + '/' + entry.name;

                            if (!fs.existsSync(sourceFilePath)) {
                                fs.mkdir(require('path').dirname(sourceFilePath), { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log("Failed to mkdir:" + err);
                                    }

                                    blobService.getBlobToStream(containerName, entry.name, fs.createWriteStream(sourceFilePath, { flags: 'a' }), options, (error, data) => {
                                        if (error) {
                                            console.log('getblobtostream error', error)
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            }
```

Error:

```
getblobtostream error Error: read ECONNRESET
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
      errno: -4077,
      code: 'ECONNRESET',
      syscall: 'read'
    }


getblobtostream error Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\tiger3\Nexus-services\node_modules\request\request.js:816:19)
{
  code: 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT',
  connect: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` is basically network error and  it can happen due to poor or unstable network or due to continuous heavy usage. Try to add retry filter on client library side.

You can try use it before getBlobToStream to create **blobservice** object .

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var retryOperations = new azure.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter();
var blobService = azure.createBlobService().withFilter(retryOperations)
```

See ***[azure storage-nodejs ,use-blob-storage. GitHub](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage.md#filters)***

**References:**

1. [ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error · Issue #604 · Azure/azure-storage-node ·
   GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/604)
2. [Using BlobService.getBlobToStream from javascript client SDK · Issue
   · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/440)

Comment: Well, OP is doing a `getBlobToStream` operation on all of their objects simultaneously - no wonder something chokes in-between.